# Quintiles de ingreso per capita en data.frame

Tags: r, rstudio

Debo agregar a un `data.frame` una nueva variable que son los ingresos per capita, en primer lugar hice esto:

```
ingreso_quintil <- quantile(base$ingreso,probs = c(0.20, 0.40, 0.60, 0.80, 1), na.rm=TRUE)
```

realice una tabla de lo anterior y en base a eso es que asigne esos valores

```
base$ingreso_quintil <-ifelse(base$ingreso_quintil<4599.590, ifelse(base$ingreso_quintil<= 4599.590 & base$ingreso_quintil< 6705.844, ifelse( base$ingreso_quintil>= 6705.844 & base$ingreso_quintil<9609.704, ifelse( base$ingreso_quintil>=9609.704 & base$ingreso_quintil<14609.581, ifelse( base$ingreso_quintil>=14609.581)))))
```

pero me da este error

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ingreso_quintil, value =
>   logical(0)) :    replacement has 0 rows, data has 2961

Comment: Revisa el código que has compartido, los `ifelse()` no cierran bien. El formato debiera ser `ifelse(<condicion>, <retorno en caso de True>, <retorno en caso de false>)`. Por otro lado, si pudieras explicar más en detalle lo que buscas, seguramente te podríamos sugerir mejores formas de resolverlo.

Comment: ' base$ingreso_quintil <-ifelse(base$ingreso_quintil<4599.590, "Primer quintil", ifelse(base$ingreso_quintil<= 4599.590 & base$ingreso_quintil< 6705.844, "Segundo quintil", ifelse( base$ingreso_quintil>= 6705.844 & base$ingreso_quintil<9609.704, "Tercer quintil", ifelse( base$ingreso_quintil>=9609.704 & base$ingreso_quintil<14609.581 & ifelse( base$ingreso_quintil>=14609.581, "Cuarto quintil", "Quinto quintil"))))) '  le agregue las condiciones pero me da el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la lógica del `ifelse()` seguramente con alguna condición estás generando 0 valores cuando se espera que hubiera 2961. Creo que es muchísimo más sencillo si usas `findInterval()` para establecer cada quintil según un determinado rango. Veamos:

```
# Armamos un ejemplo de casos
base <- data.frame(ingreso_quintil = runif(100, 0, 15000))

# Definimos los rangos (limite máximo) y los nombres que asignaremos
rangos <- data.frame(limite = c(4599.590, 6705.844, 9609.704, 14609.581, Inf),
                     nombre = c("Primer quintil", "Segundo quintil", "Tercer quintil", "Cuarto quintil", "Quinto quintil")
)

# Ahora si calculamos el quintil
base$quintil <- rangos[findInterval(base$ingreso_quintil, rangos$limite) + 1, "nombre"]

head(base, 10)
```

Salida:

```
   ingreso_quintil         quintil
1       11500.1045  Cuarto quintil
2       13193.3094  Cuarto quintil
3        4347.5344  Primer quintil
4         999.3504  Primer quintil
5       12046.4068  Cuarto quintil
6        5238.8627 Segundo quintil
7        4191.1565  Primer quintil
8        6750.4999  Tercer quintil
9         456.7855  Primer quintil
10      14767.8988  Quinto quintil
```

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias